# Got "Transaction Error" when installing SVN on Cent OS

Tags: svn, centos

I need to install svn in my project on cent OS. i got an error when i installed using yum package
that is,

```
yum --enablerepo=webtatic  install mod_dav_svn subversion

Transaction Check Error:
  package apr-1.3.12-1.w5.x86_64 (which is newer than apr-1.2.7-11.el5_6.5.i386) is already installed
  package apr-util-1.3.12-1.w5.x86_64 (which is newer than apr-util-1.2.7-11.el5_5.2.i386) is already installed

     Error Summary
     -------------
```

How to fix this issue?

PHP Version : 5.3.6

Comment: This is more related to yum rather to svn, and moreover I suppose an offtopic here on SO.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same error.
The problem is that yum is trying to install both subversion for `i386` *and* `x86/64`. The `i386` version depends on apr-utils 1.3.12, while the others depend on 1.2.7. Why is this I don't know.

I solved it just by installing the x86_64 version (for my case since my server is 64 bit):

```
yum install subversion.x86_64
```

or if you have 32 bit:

```
yum install subversion.x86
```